# JSF reveal form with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I was wondering if this is possible. I have a login form that receives an ID and password from a user. If it checks out in the backend, another form is revealed. So far I am actually sending the login details to another xhtml page to be processed. However, if the user is wrong, the page still shows.

This is my code

Index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Index</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p>Login</p>
        <h:inputText value="#{jsfbean.username}"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{jsfbean.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{jsfbean.message}" value="Results Page"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Navigation rule

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">


<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{jsfbean.getMessage}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>Success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>result.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{jsfbean.getMessage}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>Fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

jsf bean

```
 public String getMessage() {
    if(getUser(this.username,this.password)==true){
        this.userID = aUser.getUserid();
        this.secqn = aUser.getSecqn();
        this.secans = aUser.getSecans();
        return "Success";
    }else{
        return "Fail";
    }
}
```

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply redirecting to another page when user enters his username and password.

1)You need to modify your action:

```
 <h:form>
        <p>Login</p>
        <h:inputText value="#{jsfbean.username}"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{jsfbean.password}"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{jsfbean.authenticateUser}" value="Results Page"/>
    </h:form>
```

2) Write the action method inside your bean

```
    public String authenticateUser(){
    if (username!=null&&password!=null) {
        // Write your business logic here
        if (username.equals("username")&&password.equals("password")) {
            return "SUCCESS";// In your case it is result
        }
    }
    return "LOGIN";
}
```

3)Add the navigation rule

```
    <navigation-rule>
            <from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id>
            <navigation-case>
                <from-outcome>LOGIN</from-outcome>
                <to-view-id>/pages/public/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            </navigation-case>
            <navigation-case>
                <from-action>#{authenticateController.authenticateUser}</from-action>
                <from-outcome>LOGIN</from-outcome>
                <to-view-id>/pages/public/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            </navigation-case>
            <navigation-case>
                <from-action>#{authenticateController.authenticateUser}</from-action>
                <from-outcome>SUCCESS</from-outcome>
                <to-view-id>/pages/private/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
                <redirect/>
            </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is this navigation rule for JSF 1 or can I use it for 2 as well?

Comment: You can use it for JSF 2 as well.

Comment: Sorry, i'm in the middle of implementing this and have received an error javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @13,80 action="#{jsfbean.message}": Method not found: stateless.jsfbean@573e86b7.message(). I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you defined any method called message?

Comment: Please change<h:commandButton action="#{jsfbean.getMessage}" value="Results Page"/>

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't know that could be done. But I've received this message next. Its in orange for some reason. Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action '#{jsfbean.getMessage}' with outcome 'Success'

Comment: Where you put your index.xhtml?  Inside webapp?

Comment: Yeah I think it is. I've added an image of my structure

Comment: Try to put  <redirect/> in success navigation rule.

Comment: <from-view-id>>index.xhtml</from-view-id> There is one extra '>'

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you so much!